# mean value inequality proof

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am currently working through a book on differential topology and Lie groups on my own.This features in the appendix on multi-variable calculus prerequisites. I am trying to go through an outline of the proof given and reason out every step. This question is a bit long, so please bear with me. The statement is as follows:

Given $ f: (a,b) \rightarrow E $ where $ E $ is a Banach space and $ f $ is differentiable, we have ,

$$ ||f(y)-f(x)|| \leq |y-x| \sup_{0\leq t \leq 1} ||f'(x+t(y-x))|| $$

$ \forall (x,y) \in (a,b) $

Now the proof runs as follows:

The author takes an $ M\gt M_0 =\sup_{0\leq t \leq 1} ||f'(x+t(y-x))|| $  and the set

$$ S = \{ t \in [0,1]:||f(x+t(y-x))-f(x)|| \leq Mt|x-y| \} $$

This construction didnt seem natural to me.Next the author claims that S is closed. I presume that if we have a limit point $ t' $ of $ S $ and consequently a sequence $ (t_n) $ in $ S $ , then by continuity of $ f $ and the right side of the inequality , we have  $ t' $ in $ S $. Is this right?? 
Then as $ f $ is differentiable on $ (x,y) $, given $ \epsilon \lneq $ $ M-M_0 $, for all $ t $ near $ s $ and $ t \gt s $, we have:

$$ ||f(x + t(y-x))-f(x+s(y-x))-f'(x+s(y-x))(t-s)(y-x)|| \leq \epsilon |t-s||y-x| $$

I get that this inequality is due the Frechet derivative definition. But why  $ t \gt s $?
Its then shown that $ t \in S $ and hence $ s=1 $. How's this??

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Sorry, I have left out a glaring detail:that $ s = \sup S $ which exists in $ S $ obviously as $ S $ is closed and bounded.

Comment: When you write sup_{0\le t\le 1} instead of \sup_{0\le t\le 1}, then you get $\displaystyle sup_{0\le t\le 1}$ instead of $\displaystyle\sup_{0\le t\le 1}$.  The proper notation (with a backslash) also results in proper spacing in such things as $a\sup b$.  In some other respects your way of using $\TeX$ is very strange; see my edits.

Comment: Thanks for that input. Yeah I muddle up the commands mostly because I am used to LyX which has too many built in comforts :)

Comment: Hello @Vishesh , I'm wondering if you understood why $s=1$ proves the theorem and if you could give an explanation please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice to investigate arbitrary $M>M_0$ does not seem *too* unnatural to me. After all $\sup$ is the *least* upper bound, hence it is often a good idea to use all other upper bounds. Especially, as it alllows you to define a positive $\epsilon$ just when one needs one.

Closedness of $S$  should be apparent by your explicit argument or because the inverse image of a closed set (like $(-\infty,0]$) under a continuous map, like

$$t\mapsto \lVert{f(x+t(y-x))-f(x)}\rVert-Mt\lvert{x-y}\rvert$$

is always closed - this is one possible ddefinition of continuous after all.

For the rest you seem to have left out some detail.
How is $s$ defined? It cannot be just arbitray. (Otherwise a proof of $s=1$ would be a contradiction).
After your **Edit:** As $s$ is defined as $\sup S$, it seems natural to investigate $t>s$, which by definition of $\sup$ must be outside $S$, and hence a contradiction here shows that there are no $t>s$, i.e. $s=1$. The inequality is of course *valid* for all $t$ (near $s$), but in the course of the proof, we *use* it only for $t>s$.

Comment: I have edited the post. Thanks for your answer. I am also a bit unclear on the choice of $ \epsilon $.

Answer (score 2):

Theorem:
Let $g:[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be continuous, differentiable on $(a,b)$. If there is
$\beta>0$ such that $\|g'(t)\|\leq\beta$ ,for all $t\in(a,b)$, then
$\|g(b)-g(a)\|\leq\beta(b-a)$.

Proof: Define $h:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^m$ by $h(t)=g\big((1-t)a+tb\big)$.
So, $g(b)-g(a)=h(1)-h(0)$ and
$\|h'(t)\|=\|g'\big((1-t)a+tb\big)(b-a)\|\leq\beta(b-a)$.
Therefore, it is enough to prove

Lemma:
Let $h:[0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be continuous, differentiable on $(0,1)$. If there is
$\gamma>0$ such that $\|h'(t)\|\leq\gamma$ ,for all $t\in(0,1)$, then $\|h(1)-h(0)\|\leq\gamma$.

Proof: The idea is to show that
$\|h(1)-h(t)\|\leq(\gamma+\varepsilon)(1-t)$ forall $\varepsilon>0$ and forall $t\in(0,1)$.
Then, let $t\to 0^+$ with $\varepsilon$ fixed, obtaining
$\|h(1)-h(0)\|\leq\gamma+\varepsilon$. And then let $\varepsilon\to 0^+$, obtaining
$\|h(1)-h(0)\|\leq\gamma$.

Consider then $\varepsilon>0$ and $t\in(0,1)$ fixed and arbitrary. Then,
$\left\|\dfrac{h(t+s)-h(t)}{s}-h'(t)\right\|\leq\varepsilon$
for $s>0$ sufficiently small. So,
$$\|h(t+s)-h(t)\|-s\|h'(t)\|\leq\|h(t+s)-h(t)-sh'(t)\|
\leq\varepsilon s,$$
giving $\|h(t+s)-h(t)\|\leq s\|h'(t)\|+\varepsilon s\leq(\gamma+\varepsilon)s$.
Let $S=\{s\in[0,1-t]\mid\|h(t+s)-h(t)\|\leq(\gamma+\varepsilon)s\}$ and $\bar{s}=\sup S$.
We claim that $\bar{s}=1-t$. Suppose not, that is, $\bar{s}<1-t$. Then, $t+\bar{s}<1$.
Take $s>0$ sufficiently small such that $t+\bar{s}+s\leq 1$ and
$$\left\|\dfrac{h(t+\bar{s}+s)-h(t+\bar{s})}{s}-h'(t+\bar{s})\right\|
\leq\varepsilon.$$
Then, $\|h(t+\bar{s}+s)-h(t+\bar{s})\|\leq(\gamma+\varepsilon)s$.
But we have also $\|h(t+\bar{s})-h(t)\|\leq(\gamma+\varepsilon)\bar{s}$. So,
$\|h(t+\bar{s}+s)-h(t)\|\leq(\gamma+\varepsilon)s+(\gamma+\varepsilon)\bar{s}=
(\gamma+\varepsilon)(\bar{s}+s)$, giving $\bar{s}+s\in S$, a contradiction.
So, $\bar{s}=1-t$ and then, $\|h(1)-h(t)\|\leq(\gamma+\varepsilon)(1-t)$.