# What is the logic behind the last step in Hormander's proof of the mean value inequality?

Tags: vector-analysis, mean-value-theorem

My question might seem related to [this one.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208118/mean-value-inequality-proof) However, that question asks how $s=1$ was obtained and why $t>s$ was introduced. My question, on the other hand, is about why $s=1$ proves the theorem. I tried to revive that question to no avail. If anybody can give an intelligible, full answer to that question, I'll delete my post.

So, here's my question.

I'm following Hormander's "The analysis of linear partial differential operators I".

Hormander states the theorem as follows:

$$||\vec f(y)-\vec f(x)|| \leq |y-x| \sup \{||\vec f'(x+t(y-x))||, 0 \leq t \leq 1 \}$$

Then he gives the proof as follows.

Let $ M > sup \{ ||\vec f'(x+t(y-x))||, 0 \leq t \leq 1 \} $ and set $ E = \{ t;  0 \leq t \leq 1, ||\vec f(x+t(y-x))-f(x)|| \leq Mt|x-y| \} $.

Then, he justifies that $E$ has a largest element and says that if $t>s$ and $t-s$ is sufficiently small, we have

$$ ||\vec f(x+t(y-x)) - \vec f(x)|| \leq ||\vec f(x+t(y-x) - \vec f(x+s(y-x)|| + ||\vec f(x+s(y-x)) - \vec f(x)|| \leq M|(t-s)(y-x)| + Ms|y-x| = Mt|y-x| $$

Then he concludes that $s=1$ and claims it proves the theorem.

I have managed to understand why it follows from the given inequality that $s=1$. What I can't understand is why that proves the theorem.

Here's how I decipher Hormander's mathematics in this theorem.

The theorem states that the approximation can be less than or equal to the derivative. The proof, then, goes as what if we could find cases where it is bigger. Assume the approximation is bigger than the derivative, but, still, less than some arbitrary number $M$. Assume, there exists the biggest segment of the function - between the values of the parameter $t=0$ and $t=s<1$ - where the approximation is bigger than the derivative but smaller than $M$. We say, then, what if we could find a bigger segment for which the approximation is bigger than the derivative and smaller than $M$. And, indeed, we can. We keep doing that till we reach $s=1$. Then, we can state that for the entire segment of the function - between $t=0$ and $t=1$ - it is true that $||\vec f(x+t(y-x))-f(x)|| \leq Mt|x-y|$.

According to my logic, I do not see how it proves the theorem. The only thing it proves is that the approximation is always smaller than some arbitrary number $M$. But since $M$ is bigger than the derivative, the approximation can still be bigger than the derivative. Moreover, I can do the same trick with any number $M$: bigger, equal to or smaller than the derivative. In other words, we picked $M$ and did not connect it to the derivative in the course of the proof.

P.S. When I say "approximation", I mean $||\vec f(y)-\vec f(x)|| / |y-x|$. When I say "derivative", I mean $sup \{||\vec f'(x+t(y-x))||, 0 \leq t \leq 1 \}$.

---

***My comments to the accepted answer and to what I was confused about.***

I'm not a mathematician, I'm a mechanical engineer. We always derive equations. We want to understand equations deeply, fundamentally, understand what the "physics" behind them is. That's what we do in all our mechanical engineering courses. I wasn't even thinking about it, that was something I wasn't realizing, something I learnt subconsciously. Thus, when I encountered the proof of the mean value inequality, I expected to see the derivation of the mean value inequality.

That's what I was looking for. I couldn't understand that one can proof a theorem without the complete derivation. That's why I was trying to find a deeper meaning of going from $M$ to $M_0$: I thought the derivation was hidden somewhere there.

It turns out, it is a rather common trick in mathematics to prove something not by deriving it, but by showing that it is true.

That was a, fundamentally, unfamiliar and unintuitive approach to me.

Here's what is done in the proof. We assumed $M > sup \{ ||\vec f' (x + t(y-x)||, 0 \leq t \leq 1 \}$. And we proved $||\vec f(y) - \vec f(x)|| > M |x-y|$. If it works for $M$, it works for $M_0$ as well (see very nice @JackyChong's comment on that). That's it. That's all we want: to show that the original inequality $$||\vec f(y)-\vec f(x)|| \leq |y-x| \sup \{||\vec f'(x+t(y-x))||, 0 \leq t \leq 1 \}$$ does hold. We don't care about deriving it. We simply showed that it is true. It is very simple and very different from what I got used to. That is why I just couldn't wrap my head around this absolutely simple idea: don't derive, just show that it works.

I think this post can be of big importance for the people, like me, who are coming to mathematics without proper mathematical training because it explains this fundamental idea of mathematical proves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a proof by the continuity method. I will help you by filling out the gaps in the proof.

Fix $x, y \in I$ with $x\ne y$ and consider $M_0:=\sup_{0\le t\le 1}\|f'(x+t(y-x))\|$. If $M_0=\infty$, then there is nothing to prove since $\|f(x)-f(y)\|$ is finite and $|x-y|\ne 0$.

Assume $M_0<\infty$. Fix $M>M_0$ and define the set
\begin{align}
E = \{t \in [0, 1]\mid \|f(x+\tau (y-x))-f(x)\|\le M \tau|x-y| \quad \text{ for all } \tau \le t\}.
\end{align}
Clearly, $E$ is nonempty since $0 \in E$. Let us also note that $E$ is closed in $[0, 1]$: suppose $\{t_n\} \subset E$ such that $t_n \rightarrow t_\ast \in [0, 1]$, then it follows from the continuity of $f$ that
\begin{align}
\|f(x+t_\ast(y-x))-f(x)\|=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\|f(x+t_n(y-x))-f(x)\|\le \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} M t_n|x-y| = M t_\ast |x-y|.
\end{align}

Also, since $E\subset [0, 1]$, then $E$ has a supremum, say $s$. But since $E$ is closed then $s \in E$.

Here's the proof. Assume by contradiction that $s<1$, then we can choose $t\in (s, 1)$, i.e. $t>s$, with $t-s$ sufficiently small (let us quantify this later). Hence it follows that
\begin{align}
\|f(x+t(y-x))-f(x)\| \le \|f(x+s(y-x))-f(x)\|+\|f(x+t(y-x))-f(x+s(y-x))\|=: I_1 + I_2.
\end{align}

Notice that the first term $I_1$ is readily bounded by $Ms|x-y|$ since $s \in E$, i.e.
\begin{align}
 \|f(x+s(y-x))-f(x)\| \le M s|x-y|.
\end{align}
For the second term $I_2$, by the definition of differentiability, we have that
\begin{align}
\|f(x+t(y-x))-f(x+s(y-x))-f'(x+s(y-x))(t-s)(y-x)\|=o(|(t-s)(y-x)|)
\end{align}
when $t-s$ is sufficiently small, i.e. we have that
\begin{align}
\|f(x+t(y-x))-f(x+s(y-x))\| \le |(t-s)(y-x)|\|f'(x+s(y-x))\|+o(|(t-s)(y-x)|) \le M |(t-s)(y-x)|
\end{align}
when $t-s$ is sufficiently small.

This means that
\begin{align}
\|f(x+t(y-x))-f(x)\| \le&\, \|f(x+s(y-x))-f(x)\|+\|f(x+t(y-x))-f(x+s(y-x))\|\\
\le&\, Ms |y-x| + M(t-s)|y-x| = M t|y-x|.
\end{align}

Well, here we can conclude that there exists $t>s$ such that
\begin{align}
\|f(x+t(y-x))-f(x)\|\le Mt|y-x|
\end{align}
which contradicts the fact that $s$ is the supremum of $E$. Hence $s\ge 1$. But since we are working only in $[0, 1]$, then it follows that $s=1$.

Thus, we have shown that for any $M>M_0$, we have the inequality
\begin{align}
\|f(y)-f(x)\|\le M|y-x|.
\end{align}
Finally, take the limit as $M\rightarrow M_0$, we arrive at the desired theorem.

Comment: Thank you @JackyChong! You last sentence is what my question all about. I have never heard of the "continuity method", but I'm not a mathematician. I think in your last sentence you advise me to do what you did in your second equation from the top. But there, you are taking the limit with $n \rightarrow \infty$, whereas in your last inequality, there is no $t_n$. I understand the formulas (I don't quiet get, though, what $t_\ast$ and $t_n$ are), but I'm failing to grasp the fundamental meaning of them.

Comment: I'm wondering if you can give plain English explanations of what you imply by your second equation from the top (where you are taking the limits) and if you can explain how it is connected to your last sentence please (by taking the limit $M\rightarrow M_0$ and explaining why you are taking that limit).

Comment: Here's what I think your second equation from the top means (where you're taking the limits). We pick two arbitrary points $t_n$ and $t_\ast$ in the interval $[0,1]$. We assume that the derivative at $t_n$ is smaller than the derivative at $t_\ast$ which is equal to $M$. Saying $n\rightarrow \infty$, we "drag" $t_n$ to $t_\ast$, thus making the derivative at $t_n$ equal to the derivative at $t_\ast$ (which is equal to M). I'm wondering if I am correct.

Comment: @IvanNepomnyashchikh There's no $t$ in the last inequality. To be more rigorous in the proof, you start by choosing $M_n\rightarrow M_0$ from above then show that for each $n$ you have $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\le M_n|x-y|$. Finally, take the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and you are done.

Comment: To understand the second line of equation consider the following example: $F=[0, 1)$. Notice that $F$ is bounded since every value of $F$ is less than say 100 (something big or 1, doesn't really matter, and below by -100 or 0). It is clear that $\sup F = 1$ but $1\not\in F$. The reason for this is because $F$ is not closed. If a set is closed and bounded on the real line, then we know that the set attains its supremum value. Hence in the proof the point is not only to show that $\sup E = 1$ but also show that $1$ belongs in $E$.

Comment: That being said, it should be warned that the nature of the last equation is a little different than the second equation. The nature of the last inequality is as follows: you given yourself some room, i.e. work with $M_n$ slightly larger than $M_0$. For instance, you work with $M_n= M_0 + \frac{1}{n}$. This little extra freedom allows you to prove $\|f(x)-f(y)\| \le (M_0+\frac1n)|x-y|$. But since this inequality holds for any $n$, then it must be that $\|f(x)-f(y)\| \le M_0|x-y|$. If not, say $\|f(x)-f(y)\| > M|x-y|$ for some $M>M_0$, then we could choose $M_n = M_0+\frac{1}{n}<M$.

Comment: This yields the inequalities $M|x-y|<|f(x)-f(y)\| \le (M_0+\frac{1}{n})|x-y|$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you @JackyChong, that's a helpful clarification. I can think of another example $(M_0 - 1/n) \rightarrow M_0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$. Still, there is a thing I can't grasp: why do we want to take the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$? You say in your comment: "But since this inequality holds for any $n$, then it must be that $||f(x)-f(y)|| \leq M_0 |x-y|$." I can give you a counter argument: since the inequality holds for any $n$, it is true for any $M$. I.e. we didn't prove it for a particular case of $M_0$, we proved that for a multitude of all possible values of $M$, including $M_0$.

Comment: Then how do we justify that, out of the entire multitude of the values of $M$, we must pick only one value $M_0$? I understand how we do it mathematically, but I don't understand why we do it. It looks absolutely arbitrary to me.

Comment: There is a chance, I don't understand what $M$ is. I was absolutely sure it is an arbitrary number I can get from the top of my head. Am I correct? Or is there a deeper meaning to it? According to the second equation in your post (where you are taking limits), there might be a deeper meaning.

Comment: I think I've figured out why we are taking the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$. Here's my explanation. We've proved that there is some number $M$ which is always bigger than the approximation $||f(x)-f(y)||/|x-y|$. But we don't know what the number is. So, let's prove that the number is $M_0$. For that let's take the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$. That limit is supposed to tell us that $M$ converges to $M_0$. If that's correct, I'm not absolutely clear on what $n$ is and why saying "making sure $M$ converges to $M_0$" is equivalent to taking the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @IvanNepomnyashchikh I don't think I can explain it to the degree that will help you fully understand the idea. You might have to really think about it. Here's also a post by Terence Tao on this philosophy of giving yourself some room https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/28/tricks-wiki-give-yourself-an-epsilon-of-room/.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I have figured out what exactly I wanted and what you were trying to convey. I'm marking your answer as the solution (because it is the solution and it is really good, with all your clarifying comments) and I'm making an update to my post explaining what I was confused about.